# ActiveX Command Button Changes to Picture

Tags: vba, excel, button, sharepoint-2010, activex

I had a strange issue with an excel file that was saved on Sharepoint 2010. The file is a macro enabled workbook that users download and save locally. The user enters their data then pushes and ActiveX command button on the cover sheet to launch background vba code.

The problem is that now when I download the file the ActiveX button is saved as an image. I checked the versions that I added to sharepoint and the last version I added had a working ActiveX button.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Thank you